# Looking for a non parametric test for a continuos variable by two categorical variables (one with greater than 2 levels)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I have two categorical variables (one with greater than 2 levels(let's call this Categorical.variable1) and one with 2 levels (Categorical.variable2) and a continuous variable. I want to test my continuous variable grouped by Categorical.variable2 at each Categorical.variable1. Also, my continuous variable is not normally distributed so I need a non-parametric test.

I find it difficult to explain so I will re-iterate with examples- Age will be the categorical varibale in this case with greater than 2 levels (age 0 until 20 is the range). the other categorical variable is sex (M,F). Finally, the continuoes variable is weight. I want to test for signifigant differences of weight between sexes at a given age. (not comparing age 3-4 but age 3-3 between sexes). I know i can use a wilcox test to test at each individual age but im looking for a single test to do this across all ages at once.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Creating a [good reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will enhance your chances to receive appropriate help from the community.

Comment: Look into anova?

Comment: Randomization test.

Comment: I don't know if it's meaningful to test for significant difference between M/F groups. Certainly once people reach puberty, the differences are substantial, and even for earlier age groups, I suspect the differences are measurable, given that mean birth weight is different for M/F. Given all that, a significance test is just a test for whether or not you have a large data set. My advice is to estimate the magnitude of the difference instead.